# iptables rule in /etc/rc.local are not loaded

Tags: iptables, iptables-persistent

```
/etc/iptables.conf
```

contains a rule to dump my outgoing packets to 10.199 network as,

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [122:9273]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [73:8165]
-A OUTPUT -d 10.199.48.0/24 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
```

To ensure, these rules are added on every machine boot, i have added this rule in `/etc/rc.local` as,

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf
```

But on every bootup, the iptables are not loaded with this new rule. I am using Centos 7.0.1406.

This instructions i am following from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66890/how-can-i-make-a-specific-set-of-iptables-rules-permanent).

Comment: Is the rule actually meant for `10.199.x.x` network or `10.199.48.x` network? Because the rules says `/24` ! Just asking....

Comment: Look for the guide for your own distribution, not for Ubuntu.  Here's [RHEL7 Security Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html).  Related: http://serverfault.com/q/626521/290746

Comment: @Neuron, it is meant for 10.199.48.x network...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/rc.local` is a symlink to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` in `CentOS 7` so you have to ensure that `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` is executable if you want to start things this way, so you can do:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

and then to start the service:

```
systemctl start rc-local
```